# Gitlab CI cannot access vagrant domain

Tags: yii2, gitlab-ci, codeception

Disclaimer: Newbie question. I just started codeception and CI few weeks ago.

I am currently doing a project using yii2 and vagrant. I was able to run my tests on the vagrant.
[image]

However when I use Gitlab CI 2 of my acceptance tests did not run properly. 1 is an error and 1 is a failure.

[image]

My hunch is that Gitlab CI cannot access the domain I created for my vagrant which is http://yiitesting.dev

I hope somebody here can offer some help. Thanks